# java sql insert preparedstatment error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, netbeans

```
String sql = " INSERT INTO `tblservice` (`ServiceID`,`accountID`, `Kind`, `Description`, `Price`, "
        + "`Quantity`, `Total`, `DateAndTime`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstm.setInt(1, this.accountID);
pstm.setString(2, "" + SelectionBox.getSelectedItem());
pstm.setString(3, desc);
pstm.setFloat(4, Float.parseFloat(PriceTF.getText()));
pstm.setFloat(5, Float.parseFloat(QuantityTF.getText()));
pstm.setFloat(6, this.getTotal());
pstm.setDate(7, dateAdded);

pstm.executeUpdate();
```

**Error**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
```

Comment: Where is the question? Where is the context? We need more information so we can try to help you...

Comment: The error message told you what to do.  What is your question?

Comment: I'm currently using a button to trigger that code, and everytime i pressed the button it keep displaying that error and nothing operations trigger I mean no data is being inserted. that's should not be it supposed to add new data in the table but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of make NULL in your query `VALUES (NULL, ...)` use `setNull` for example :

```
pstm.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

It will take the type, of your field, in this example i consider it is a `java.sql.Types.INTEGER` it can be `java.sql.Types.VARCHAR` or any [sql type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html)

So your query should be like this :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblservice (ServiceID, accountID, Kind, Description, 
               Price, Quantity, Total, DateAndTime) 
               VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstm.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
pstm.setInt(2, this.accountID);
....
```

Comment: thank's for your answer bro. i've tried your advice but still the same error it  returns   .error occur because : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

Comment: are you sure about the type of your fields `accountID` i think it is an int in your database and not a String, i'm wrong? @meltits

Comment: I've Updated syntax below but still the same error occured

Comment: String sql = " INSERT INTO `tblservice` (`ServiceID`,`accountID`, `Kind`, `Description`, `Price`, `Quantity`, `Total`, `DateAndTime`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                  PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: @meltits did you set `pstm.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);` ?

Comment: Yes bro it is int in my database that's why i used setInt. or do i need to remove the single quote for accountID because it is int. @ YCF_L

Comment: @meltits why you set `NULL` for `ServiceID` ?

Comment: String sql = "INSERT INTO `tblservice` (`ServiceID`,`accountID`, `Kind`, `Description`, `Price`,`Quantity`,`Total`,`Date and time`) "
           + "VALUES (NULL,'"+this.accountID+"', '"+SelectionBox.getSelectedItem()+"', '"+desc+"', '"+Float.parseFloat(PriceTF.getText())+"', '"+Float.parseFloat(QuantityTF.getText())+"', '"+this.getTotal()+"', '"+dateAdded+"');";     - this code is working but for Statement only and not PreparedStatement. I intent to used PreparedStatement to in order for it to accept apostrophe and ignore apostrophe for sql injection vurnerabilities

Comment: no no @meltits the one that you use Prepapred Stetement

Comment: is set ServiceID to null because in my database it is autoIncremented

Comment: String sql = " INSERT INTO `tblservice` (`ServiceID`,`accountID`, `Kind`, `Description`, `Price`, "
        + "`Quantity`, `Total`, `DateAndTime`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

Comment: no no @meltits it is auto_increment, then don't set it in your query at all ok try without setting `ServiceID` and let me know

Comment: String sql = " INSERT INTO `tblservice` (`accountID`, `Kind`, `Description`, `Price`, `Quantity`, `Total`, `DateAndTime`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";run:
error occur because : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

Comment: @meltits can try removing the quotes in your fields?

Comment: what quotes do you mean single or the double one

Comment: @meltits try to use a new version of JDBC use the 5.xxx version and try again

Comment: i followed of your suggestions @ YCF_L and finally my code runs well and here my new updated code:

Comment: String sql = "INSERT INTO `tblservice` (`ServiceID`,`accountID`, `Kind`, `Description`, `Price`,`Quantity`,`Total`,`DateAndTime`) "
                   + "VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
                   PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: you are welcome @meltits if that help you thank you to accept the answer